# SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler does not work as intended when session timeout in spring security

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-security

I'm using Spring Security `4.2.2.RELEASE` in my application. Once the session timeout happens and then if the user click any URL, it gets redirected to logout page and once the authentication is successful, it redirects to the default Home page, not the previously requested page.

So I tried to workaround this behavior by adding following configurations to the servlet.xml file.

```
  <security:form-login
            login-page="/login"
            authentication-failure-url="/login_error"
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password"
            always-use-default-target="false"
            authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"
            />

 <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll"/>

 <bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <property name="useReferer" value="true" />
</bean>
```

What could be gone wrong here? Please someone explain why this does not work?

Comment: The initial request is stored in the session, there is no session hence nothing to store and thus after login nothing to re-execute. Only using the referrer header won't be enough as there could be a request body involved etc.